# Resizing the content of UIWebView?

Tags: ios, webview

A noob here so it might take a while to understand what's the wrong, just follow along ..
the key purpose of my app is to download an xml file from rss feed then parse it and pass it as html file to a webview with this method: `[webView loadHTMLString:aString baseURL:nil]`

after the content took place in the webview it doesn't fit nice and neat instead there's some photos in the content that has a width larget than what it can be displayed at once without scrolling horizontally,as well as the attachments at the end of the webview you have to scroll a bit right or left to read the full name of it, it'd be nice if the content stretched so it can be seen without scrolling horizontally.

Notice that I adjusted webview property scalesPageToFit to be YES, but that scaled the content to very small size to the point that you can't read what it contains!
any solution around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a meta/viewport tag and se the content width.  See documentation, here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: Perfect ,work like a charm!, thanks, i used this tag: <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width"> now the content fits inside the width of the screen